# Footer has disappeared (fancyhdr)

Tags: header-footer, footer

I should have a grey footer with some words on the left and company name on right, plus a page number, all starting after title page. Instead I get no footer below my tables. I'm very new to using latex in a meaningful way. What has gone wrong here? Using xelatex. Providing a link to my latex mfe as a file in google drive due to character limit. Thanks in advance.

[template.tex](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PHOQBrdXZU8UuGhm4XX6z1F2J2jzsBZh/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  For future reference, it's better to trim what you have down to a minimal working example that shows your problem, and then post the code here.  If you move or change your google drive file, then your question is much harder or impossible to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Welcome, mb158127!** Hopefully, you'll find this website useful!

---

### Solution

To make the footer appear, comment out (or just remove) the call to `\fancyfoot{}` on line 118 of the `template.tex` document:

```
...
\begin{titlepage}
%Change margins for title page
    \newgeometry{top=.5cm,bottom=0cm, left=0cm, right = 0cm}

%Import header and footer/but remove footer
    \thispagestyle{fancy}
    %\fancyfoot{} % <----- The source of the issue with the footer

%Set up left side of page
   \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
...
```

---

### Explanation

The call to `\fancyfoot{}` affects all the pages in the document starting from the page where this call is made and all the subsequent pages, not just the title page.

The call on the previous line to `\thispagestyle{fancy}`, which only affects the current page, seems to be sufficient to remove the footer from only the (current) title page, so there is no need, thankfully, to call `\fancyfoot{}`.

Alternatively, if you would like to have the `\fancyfoot{}` command issued anyway on the title page, you may do so by defining your own style, in which you call `\fancyfoot{}`, and passing this style to the `\thispagestyle` command (e.g., `\thispagestyle{MyStyle}`,) as **Schweinebacke** demonstrates in the accepted answer to [Different header and footer on the title page (first page)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/351542/different-header-and-footer-on-the-title-page-first-page).

---

### Demonstration that the solution works

For your reference and easier comparison, shown below are the pages from the output PDF file before and after commenting out `\fancyfoot{}`. The only difference between the output pages is that, after we commented out `\fancyfoot{}`, the footer appears on all the pages that come after the title page, exactly as you planned it to be.

#### Note about the graphics included in the document

Please note that since the graphics that are embedded into the `TeX` file via `includegraphics` are not enclosed in the question (understandably,) I briefly commented them out to make the document compile. Including these graphics should not interfere with the `fancyhdr` package, so you should see the footer in any case.

**Page 1, before the change**

[image]

**Page 1, after the change** (There is no difference since the title page is unchanged.)

[image]

**Page 2, before the change**

[image]

**Page 2, after the change** (Note the gray footer at the bottom.)

[image]

**Page 3, before the change**

[image]

**Page 3, after the change** (Note the footer at the bottom, here too.)

[image]

---

### Final Comments

If you find `fancyhdr` helpful in getting various projects done, you may look up useful commands and learn more about `thispagestyle` in the `fancyhdr` user manual at https://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.pdf.

Hopefully, this approach above addressed your question! If it hasn't, I will be more than happy to adjust the answer accordingly to adequately address your question.

Comment: thanks for the great answer & explanation

Comment: @mb158127, you are welcome, and thank you! Please let me know if there are any questions on this topic!