# Apply fancyhdr pagestyle to title page

Tags: titles, fancyhdr

I'm trying to apply a pagestyle to the front page of my thesis (because it's required by my institution), but I can't get a way to make it. I have tried with \pagestyle{style} after and before my \begin{titlepage}, as same as \thispagestyle{style}.

Here's my MWE (tryied to reduce it as much as possible):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish, es-tabla]{babel} % pone el idioma en español

\usepackage{lipsum} % dummy text

\usepackage{geometry} % margenes del documento
\geometry{letterpaper, top = {2,5cm}, bottom = {2,5cm}, inner = {2,5cm},
    outer = {2,5cm}, head = {1,1cm}, foot = {1,1cm}, bindingoffset = {1,0cm}}
% Si se va a usar dos paginas por hoja, agregar la opción twoside

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\chapter}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{\thispagestyle{fancy}}{}{} % necesario para poner encabezado en paginas de capítulos

% paquete para encabezado y pie de pagina 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\fancypagestyle{mystyle}

\pagestyle{mystyle} % Aplicar el estilo de numeración de página personalizado


% - - - - - T E R M I N O - C O M A N D O S - - - - -

\fancypagestyle{mystyle}{
    \fancyhead{}
    \fancyfoot{}
    \fancyhead[L]{\footnotesize{\begin{tabular}{@{}c} 
                Text\\
                Text\\ 
                Text
    \end{tabular}}}
    \fancyhead[R]{{\footnotesize{Text}}}
    
    \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
    \fancyheadoffset[lh]{0.85cm}
}

\fancypagestyle{portada}{
    \fancyhead{}
    \fancyfoot{}
    \fancyhead[L]{\footnotesize{\begin{tabular}{@{}c} 
                Text\\
                Text\\ 
                Text
        \end{tabular}}}
    \fancyhead[R]{{\footnotesize{Text}}}
    
    \fancyheadoffset[lh]{0.85cm}
}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{portada}
\begin{titlepage}
    \vspace*{10cm}
    \begin{center}
        \fontsize{20pt}{1.5em} \selectfont \textbf{\MakeUppercase{``Title of the thesis''}}
    \end{center}
\end{titlepage}

\clearpage

\pagestyle{mystyle}

\chapter{Text}

\lipsum[1-3]

\end{document}
```

The output is:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Move the `\thispagestyle{…}` behind `\begin{titlepage}`, because the `titlepage` has it's own `\thispagestyle{empty}`, which otherwise overwrites your one before `\begin{titlepage}`. If the `\thispagestyle{…}` is inside the `titlepage` environment, it overwrites the one of `titlepage`.

Comment: You can find a more general solution in the second example of  [Schweinebacke's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/351552/277964) to [Different header and footer on the title page (first page)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/351542/277964)

Answer (score 0):

As @cabohah mentioned, the solution to this problem is to move `\thispagestyle{portada}` inside the `\begin{titlepage}`, like this:

```
\begin{titlepage}
    \thispagestyle{portada}
    .
    .
    .
\end{titlepage}
```

This is because `\begin{titlepage}` defines it own pages tyle `\thispagestyle{empty}`